# Getting the email address from known login name in Liferay 6.1 EE

Tags: jsp, liferay, liferay-6

A user is beeing verified by entering her/his login name to access a Liferay 6.1 EE portal.

As i said we know the users login name.

Is it possible to obtain the users email address from the given login name within a jsp template ?

I have the following code snippet which checks whether the email address is "valid" or not.

But to run this script i need to get email address from the login-name...

```
<aui:script>
                <!-- email should look like this: specfonds.xxx@test.at -->
                <!-- url="\<\%= forgotPasswordURL %>" -->

                function checkEmail() {
                    var checkEmail = document.getElementById("_58_validation_check").value;
                    var regex = "specfonds\.\S*"

                    if(checkEmail.match(regex)) {
                        var redirectMessage = document.getElementById("redirectMessage").setAttribute("style","style=display:block;");
                    } else {
                        window.location.href='<%= forgotPasswordURL %>';

                    }                   
                }       
        </aui:script>
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: you wan't to know the email before user is logged ?  or user is logged in?

Comment: i need the email before the user is looged in...

Comment: @HelmutSteiner Have you handled the possibility of getting an incorrect screename,and the subsequent exception when getting exception while fetching User.That would eventually need exception handling.I suggest you should go for a pre-login hook,rather than having java code all in script within jsp.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is already logged, you can get this user information from the ThemeDisplay (themeDisplay.getUser()) or via PortalUtil (PortalUtil.getUser(PortletRequest)).

If not, you can get this information with this method: UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmail(long companyId, String screenName).

Regards.

Comment: Is this the right approach to get the companyId -> Long companyId = CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId();

Comment: That is a valid approach, but maybe not the best one. If you can access to ThemeDisplay, you can get companyId from it. If you are working on a JSP, you can initalize ThemeDisplay and other stuff with the tag <liferay-theme:defineObjects />